# Text color of select options visible when dropdown opened?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to give every option in a dropdown its own text color ?
I have tried to achieve this using css and/or jQuery, but nothing happens.
Tested it in FF.
To be more clear: when I open the dropdown, I'd like to see the options in there, all having their own text color. I don't need the selected option that is visible after closing the dropdown to retain the color.

What I tried:

```js
$('#sel option:selected').css('color', 'red');
```

```css
.a {
  color: red;
}

.b {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option class="a" value="1">Bla1</option>
  <option class="b" value="2">Bla2</option>
</select>
```

When I look in FF at the element, I can see that it has

style="color: red;"

not show it.

To be even more clear:
The intention is that the user will select an option, and can come back to the same dropdown to see that the option(s) selected earlier were already processed. It is allowed to select the already processed option again, and therefore all options need to stay in the dropdown.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: When I look at your snippet in FF 53.0.2 (32-bit) on Windows 10, the two options have different colors. Of course, the highlight color is the same for both, so you need to move the highlight between the two options in order to see the colors...

Comment: Strange. The only difference is that my FF is 64 bit. And I do not see colored options...

Comment: Yep. I just installed the 64-bit version and can see the same thing. I suggest you use the feedback option or [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) for this.

Comment: Thanks! Thought I was going mad....

Comment: Just filed a bug. Let's see what happens...tnx!

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to create an answer for this question, detailing what we found, and a link to the bug report. I'd upvote that :).

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below, this might help you!!

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){

$("#sel").val('2');
$("#sel").on('change',function(){
   
    if($(this).find("option:selected").val()== 1)
     {
       $("body").css("background-color","#D83F21");    
      }
     else{
      $("body").css("background-color","#FFF");
       }
  });
  
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<select id="sel">
  <option class="a" value="1">Bla1</option>
  <option class="b" value="2">Bla2</option>
</select>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this behaviour occurs in the 64 bit version of FF 53.0.2. Other people have confirmed this.
It is, however, working in the 32 bit version of the same FF 53.0.2. All tests in Win 10.

I have filed a bugreport with Mozilla: [Bug 1363152](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363152)